# Best gui for remote gdb

Tags: c, gdb, remote-debugging

I know this question has been brought up before but it was mostly in respect to `gdb` for a program running on the local machine.

I've had some success with `eclipse-cdt` but it only seems to work occasionally. Supposedly `Insight` was previously used to debug (this embedded `x86` board) but it seems to be dead.

I only need C debugging not C++. If possible I would prefer to connect through `gdbserver` (as that is on the advice and I connect to it through the command line all the time) but if you think putting `gdb` or `ssh` on the device and using it through those is better please mention those solutions also.

P.S. The version of `gdbserver` on the device is 7.1 it would be nice if the solution can work with a compatible version of `gdb` but I might be able to install a different `gdbserver` version.

Comment: What troubles do you have with Eclipse? I'm using it to debug embedded platforms(ARM and Atom based) with gdbserver running on the targets and it works great for me.

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Comment: what's wrong with tool recomendations> Stack overflow has a ton of great questions about tool recomendations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend eclipse Indigo it has built-in support for remote debugging applications via gdbserver. I just don't know where the source code has to be located for it to work.

Sinec it uses the MI interface of gdb it should work as any other interface that interacts with gdb.

Comment: Previously it wouldn't show code initially till I continued past start of main function andreload the view(I think or something like that). Currently w/ eclipse 3.7 breakpoints/showing code as opposed to assembly doesn't work. The remote build is definitely a debug build(I'm pretty sure the local one is as well).

Comment: Breakpoints by clicking on the left side of the windows also don't work for me. I set them manually with the output windows and the standard 'break' command from gdb. The code only starts to show when you 'break' the running process so that the interface can synch with gdb.

Comment: I think that is what I used to be able to do but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

Comment: fixed it, now need to add "file binary-name" after connection

Answer (score 5):

I recommend trying out [Qt Creator](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator). It's cross-platform, has pretty good "code insight" features, and is a hell of a lot lighter-weight than Eclipse. It is a full IDE, not just a debugger front-end. It does require a gdb built with python support (client only, I think), but does come with it in its cross-platform installer. It is definitely more geared to developing C++/Qt applications, but does support generic Makefile and CMake projects, and I use it as my everyday C IDE and debugger.

Depending on exactly what kind of remote target you're debugging, the answer to this question could vary a lot. If you're cross-debugging to a deeply embedded microcontroller target running an RTOS, your options are going to be more limited.

For Makefile-based projects, you want to use the ["Generic Project" creation wizard](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-generic.html), which by default adds all the source files under the specified directory to your project. It may take some manual work to maintain your project, if you want Qt Creator to "understand" things that you've specified in your Makefile like command-line include directories (go in your .includes file), command-line included headers (go in your .config file), and command-line symbol definitions (go in your .config file). The project file list and compile, deploy, and run commands can all be maintained from the GUI though.

Comment: Which version are you using, w/2.2 I can't find any way to import makefile projects

Comment: Qt does not use Makefiles to build it's project but relies on it's own build mechanism with 'qmake'.

Comment: Yes but I need to debug makefile projects. I could use auto-generated files but I doubt there is an auto generator.

Comment: The manual has [a section on creating generic projects](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.2/creator-project-generic.html). 
Basically you just end up creating a list of the files in your project (which can also be maintained from the UI). It also allows you to put in the .config file symbols that might be defined and includes that may be included normally via the command line. And it has a .includes file in which you can list extra include dirs that are in your Makefile. It is completely manual, but it does work for me...

Answer (score 4):

Gdb itself has already built-in [curses based pseudo gui](http://sources.redhat.com/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/TUI.html). By default, it splits main screen on 2 windows. Upper window contains source code, lower window is command line interface. Also there are other modes allowing to show you register values and assembly. It works well over ssh, so if you can, copy gdb on your device and debug it over ssh. If not, everything above can be applied for debugging over gdbserver.

Answer (score 4):

How about using DDD? I haven't used it much to be honest, and there seems to be a way to do remote debugging using DDD http://www.gnu.org/s/ddd/manual/html_mono/ddd.html#Remote%20Program

Comment: wheee!! Thanks! My first bounty answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use NetBeans. NetBeans support remote debugging with gdb. Gdbserver support plug-in also exist. I don't test plug-in but remote debugging using ssh working well.

Comment: gdbserver plugin chokes for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try **[Affinic Debugger GUI](http://www.affinic.com/?page_id=109)**.  It has newer design.
DDD is too old, Affinic Debugger supports all major platforms and is more powerful than DDD.